# Malformed patch error on AIX machine

Tags: aix, patch

I'm created a SVN patch to port from a Linux server to AIX server.

The SVN generated patch is as below:

```
Index: cas/cm/cmsee.c
===================================================================
--- cas/cm/cmsee.c      (revision 19)
+++ cas/cm/cmsee.c      (working copy)
@@ -769,14 +769,23 @@

 CE_CEXPFCT CE_VOID cm_seet(CE_VOID)
 {
+#ifndef TRACE
+   TT_OWNTYPE  *phh;
+   TT_OWNTYPE  *phhe;
+#elif FINAL_CHECKS
    TT_OWNTYPE  *phh;
    TT_OWNTYPE  *phhe;
+#endif

    TRACE(I,"cm_seet");

+#ifndef TRACE
    phh  = cm_fp->fp_hh_ptr;
    phhe = phh + cm_fp->cp_hh_cnt;
-
+#elif FINAL_CHECKS
+   phh  = bm_fp->fp_hh_ptr;
+   phhe = pht + bm_fp->fp_hh_cnt; 
+#endif
    TRACE(I, fstr("init: phh %x phhe %x\n", phh, phhe););

 #ifdef FINAL_CHECKS
```

When I run the command

```
patch -p0 -i Modified.patch
```

I get the follow error:

```
Hmm...  Looks like a unified context diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: cas/cm/cmsee.c
|===================================================================
|--- cas/cm/cmsee.c     (revision 19)
|+++ cas/cm/cmsee.c     (working copy)
--------------------------
Patching file cas/cm/cmsee.c using Plan A...
Malformed patch at line 7:  CE_CEXPFCT CE_VOID cm_seet(CE_VOID)
```

I tried Google and checked on StackExchange, but no solutions which could solve my problem. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Which version of AIX? It seems the versions of `patch` provided in 5.3 and below do not support unified diffs, but later versions should. If you have an earlier version, you could build another `patch`, such as GNU's, or generate non-unified diffs

Comment: Does it help if you explicitly tell `patch` that it's a unified diff, with the `-u` flag?

Comment: It's been a while, but the combination of `-p0` and the two-level directory structure confuses me; are you in the `cas/cm/` directory? Or should you use `-p2`?

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are encountering is a bug in the AIX implementation of `patch`. Specifically, at least some versions of the AIX implementation of `patch` expect unified context diff files to be in the erroneous form produced by (at least some versions of) the AIX `diff` utility. Said erroneous form does not conform to POSIX and contains a space in the second column of each line of context and of each added or deleted line.

To use a unified context diff (in the form described by POSIX) with affected versions of the AIX `patch` utility, a space needs to be inserted into the second column of each of the lines that represent context, additions, or deletions.

For the `Modified.patch` file that you described, an adjusted patch file can be produced using:

```
( head -n 4 Modified.patch; tail -n +5 Modified.patch |
  sed 's/^$/ /; s/^\([ +-]\)/\1 /;' ) > Adjusted.patch
```